# jhipster import-jdl error in jhipster monolith app when jdl has user entity relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, jhipster

I am trying to generate my monolith application using jhipster, but I haven't been successful. After troubleshooting I realized the issue is caused whenever I have a relationship to the user entity. To demonstrate the issue I have created a sample jhipster applications with a simple jdl which I copied from this link https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/01/20/reactive-java-microservices, but instead of a microservice am generating a monolith application using spring webflux. I have jhipster version 7.8.0 installed. Here is my yo.rc

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "blog",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "flatly",
    "clientThemeVariant": "primary",
    "creationTimestamp": 1649012211769,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "blg",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.8.0",
    "jwtSecretKey": "NjZlYjBlMTEzMjJiNmZiODFhYzc5NDk3OWM2YzY4NjM3ZjNkN2YwZDAxMDE1NzQ1OTc5MGQxM2ViNDMxMTYxYmEzZmI5NjEzOTI4Mzc4MjU0NjQyMWZmNDBiYTFjNzNmNzY2MTM0Y2JkNTJjMTI0MzU4NjUzMThlZjQyZTU4ZGM=",
    "languages": ["en", "fr"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "com.blog",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": true,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}
```

Also here is my app-jdl.jdl

```
entity Blog {
  name String required minlength(3)
  handle String required minlength(2)
}

entity Post {
  title String required
  content TextBlob required
  date Instant required
}

entity Tag {
  name String required minlength(2)
}

entity Product {
  title String required
  price BigDecimal required min(0)
  image ImageBlob
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Blog{user(login)} to User
  Post{blog(name)} to Blog
}

relationship ManyToMany {
  Post{tag(name)} to Tag{post}
}

paginate Post, Tag with infinite-scroll
paginate Product with pagination
```

when I run `jhipster import-jdl app-jdl.jdl`  I get the following error

```
Error running generator entities: Error: Error parsing file src/main/java/com/blog/repository/BlogRepositoryInternalImpl.java: undefined
```

[image]
[image]

If you have any solution on how to go around this, please share. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

JHipster's JWT Auth doesn't support relationships with `User` in microservices. That feature is only available with OAuth 2.0.

https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-microservices/

Comment: but I was not generating a microservice, I was generating a monolith. Hence it should work

Comment: It might be because you're using reactive, which uses R2DBC. If you use non-reactive, it'll use JPA and should work.

Comment: Is there a way to get it working for reactive with R2DBC for monolith in jhipster? since in my requirements I have to use the reactive stack with postgress hence its practically impossible to avoid them. if I wanted to build a monolith with the reactive stack with R2DBC using jhipster, how would you advice I go about it?

Comment: I tried creating an app from scratch using `jhipster` and answering the questions appropriately. I did this and then ran `jhipster jdl blog.jdl` using the JDL above. I'm able to reproduce the error. It could be a bug or possibly just an unsupported feature.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, really appreciate

Comment: For anyone following along, you can find this issue in JHipster's bug tracker at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18293.